# PostCSS hangs when I run it. No ouput, no error

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I have postcss-cli installed globally, and postcss installed in my project. However, when I run `postcss input.css -o output.css --watch`, it just hangs with no output.

I'm using it with TailwindCSS. Here is my postcss.config.js if that is helpful:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'tailwindcss': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    'autoprefixer': {},
  }
}
```